# loading multiple files using Silverlight with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-2.0

I have developed one project by using silverlight 2 with asp.net.

I have one silverlight application and two .aspx pages (one for login.aspx and another for registration). I have designed login.aspx using silverlight 2 and I have attached .xap file to my login.aspx.

For registration.aspx. I need to developed one more silverlight app.

My question is; if I have 10 .aspx pages do I need to developed 10 silverlight applications?

Thanks

Ravi kumar

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about URLs being nicely displayed to users then I would consider ASP.NET MVC or load the same xap from both pages and pass in a parameter to the SL app to tell it whether is should show the login or registration form.

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189004(VS.95).aspx) for how to pass custom parameters into a SL application from an HTML page: